# (400) Bad Request using Google API PHP Client with the Admin SDK

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) with the Google Directory API. I went into the Google Developers Console and created a project called `google-sync`. I then enabled the `Admin SDK` in the APIs list page. I then selected "Create new Client ID" from the Credentials page, and selected `Service Account`, and then downloaded the .bin private key that I was prompted to download. I then also clicked on "Generate new P12 key" and downloaded the .p12 file, which was placed in the same directory as the PHP file.

Here's my PHP code (which follows [this part of the docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service)) that is trying to list all users.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit';

$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<EMAIL ADDRESS>';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '<P12 FILE NAME>.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('google-sync');
$adminService = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    array($SCOPE),
    $key);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

$allUsers = $adminService->users->listUsers();
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (400) Bad Request' in /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:80
Stack trace:

#0 /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(499): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Directory.php(2063): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#4 /projects/google-sync/auth-test.php(20): Google_Service_Directory_Users_Resource->listUsers()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 80

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (400) Bad Request' in /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 80

Google_Service_Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users: (400) Bad Request in /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 80

Call Stack:
    0.0001     232296   1. {main}() auth-test.php:0
    0.0172    2957992   2. Google_Service_Directory_Users_Resource->listUsers() /projects/google-sync/auth-test.php:20
    0.0172    2959144   3. Google_Service_Resource->call() /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Directory.php:2063
    0.3356    2970752   4. Google_Client->execute() /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:195
    0.3356    2971568   5. Google_Http_REST::execute() /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:499
    0.7015    2974424   6. Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse() /projects/google-sync/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:44
```

When I downloaded the p12 file, I was given a password associated with the private key, but I'm unable to find any documentation on how that password should be included. Is this my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by going into my domain's Admin Console, went to the Manage API client access page under Security, and added the Client Id from the Developer Console and added the scopes I needed for the Directory API.

See [this part of the docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) for more info.

Comment: i want to access google groups information (from workspace), my purpose is add member by some application to google groups, i have setup these scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly ) Now i am getting 400 bad request error in my application, following https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php this. can you help me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Service account should impersonate a domain admin when it makes the request. In addition, listUsers() expects the domain to be passed as an argument.

Makes sure that you've delegated domain-wide authority to the service account - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array($SCOPE),
    $key
);
$cred->sub = "admin@domain.com";
//Get All users.
$list  = $service->users->listUsers(Array('domain' => 'domain.com'));
//Get one user
$userId = $service->users->get('someuser@domain.com');
```